# Rails, CanCan nested forms security issue. Read allows to do anything with model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, nested-forms, cancan, nested-attributes

On my site, customer can create some groups and products. Every product is belongs_to group.
Every user can create and update groups, but only which they create themself.
I'm using CanCan gem to restrict permissions, and it works great, but I faced the problem:

If I give to user permission for creating group while creating a product, like this:
(Simplified example)
View:

```
= form_for @product
 = f.fields_for :group do |builder|
   = builder.label 'Group name'
   = builder.text_field :group
```

Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  attr_accessible :group_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :group
end

class Gift < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

Ability:

```
cannot :manage, :all
can :manage, Product, group_id: user.group_id
can :manage, Group, user_group_id: user.group_id
```

So, user can do anything on only what he created (or what created by anybody in his user group, but forget about this – in my example one user per user_group)

Products and Groups are working properly, restricting acceess. Problem is in security with nested resource.
In ProductsController I call

```
load_and_authorize_resource only: [:index, :show, :new, :destroy, :edit, :update]
authorize_resource only: [:create] #do some extra actions before authorize & save
```

So, when I'm trying update any group, even it's not belong to user – it updates. Ok, I need to load and authorize Group resource.
But

```
load_and_authorize_resource only: [:index, :show, :new, :destroy, :edit, :update]
authorize_resource only: [:create]
load_and_authorize_resource :gift
```

Or

```
load_and_authorize_resource only: [:index, :show, :new, :destroy, :edit, :update]
authorize_resource only: [:create]
load_and_authorize_resource :gift, through: :product
```

give no result.

Trying to play with params, I find that allowing read on a model with any params grant full access through nested objects. For example,

```
can :read , Group, group_id: -1
```

And I can do anything through association with nested attributes, e.g. update.
Also, I tried to fix my problem with other way – finding how to create a new group, if it has nested attributes – not a brilliant way, but it will block hackers. But accept_nested_attributes has only argument update_only, no create_only, so, I decided to ask here. Where I'm wrong?